# Integer.toBinaryString() not correctly converting to binary

Tags: java, binary

I am currently working on a Vernam cipher program, and a big part of that is the ability to convert plaintext into binary. I looked into how to do this, and I found that `Integer.toBinaryString()` would work best in converting each individual character of the plaintext to binary. For most characters, this conversion works, however, I have found instances that cause me to run into an error in the conversion.

For example, whenever I run this code: `System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString('€'));` I would expect an output of `10000000`, however, I get `10000010101100` outputted instead. According to [this ASCII Table](https://www.ascii-code.com/), I know extended ASCII characters can have some variation on values, however, most of the characters in this table are accurate in the extended ASCII character section, the Euro is represented by 128 in ASCII.

Why is `Integer.toBinaryString('€')` returning `10000010101100`? Is there a way I can fix this?

Comment: A Java char is a 2 byte value that represents a Unicode code point, not an ASCII value.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen Really? I thought java characters represented ASCII values because when you cast them to ints don't they return the ASCII value of the character? I could be wrong on this, and probably am.

Comment: Definitely [unicode](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.4). The integer value of '€' is 8364: https://ideone.com/oGXv0h

Comment: Integer values for the first 128 Unicode code points would indeed be the same as ASCII. The first 256 code points correspond to ISO/IEC 8859-1 if I remember correctly. The euro character is not in any of these character sets.

Comment: @Aditya `System.out.println((int)'€')` prints `8364`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.4), §3.10.4:

> Character literals can only represent UTF-16 code units (§3.1)

When you call `Integer.toBinaryString()`, the char literal is implicitly converted (widened) to an `int`, so it's replaced with the corresponding code unit value, which is 8364 for '€'. The binary representation for 8364 is indeed 10000010101100, so the method behaves correctly.

To encode '€' using CP1252 code page, which is listed on the web-site you are referring to, you may use a specific Charset object:

```java
ByteBuffer buffer = Charset.forName("CP1252").encode("€");
System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(buffer.get() & 0xFF)); // prints 10000000
```